# SQL SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE, PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I need to take data from a table that looks like this:

```
  name    |  server  |  instance  | version  |   user  
----------|----------|------------|----------|---------  -  
package_a |     x    |     1      |    1     |    AB  
package_b |     x    |     1      |    1     |    TL  
package_a |     x    |     2      |    4     |    SK  
package_a |     y    |     1      |    2     |    MD  
package_c |     y    |     1      |    4     |    SK  
package_b |     y    |     2      |    1     |    SK  
package_a |     y    |     2      |    1     |    TL  
package_b |     x    |     2      |    3     |    TL  
package_c |     x    |     2      |    1     |    TL
```

and I need to put it in a table like that:

```
  name    | v_x_1 | u_x_1 | v_x_2 | u_x_2 | v_y_1 | u_y_1 | v_y_2 | u_y_2 
----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|------- 
package_a |   1   |   AB  |   4   |   SK  |   2   |   MD  |   1   |   TL
package_b |   1   |   TL  |   3   |   TL  |  NULL |  NULL |   1   |   SK
package_c |  NULL |  NULL |   1   |   TL  |   4   |   SK  |  NULL |  NULL
```

I already tried `INSERT` with `(SUB)SELECT`, tried to `INSERT` package names first using `DISTINCT` and `UPDATE` afterwards, played around with `PIVOT` and stuff like that.

But I'm rather new to SQL and programming in general, so I couldn't come up with a solution. Since I not only have a version number in the source table but also `nvarchar` columns, It seems like `PIVOT` won't be the way to go, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIVOT on a sub query that uses UNION to separate the user and version values.

```sql
insert into YourNewTable (name, [v_x_1],[u_x_1],[v_x_2],[u_x_2],[v_y_1],[u_y_1],[v_y_2],[u_y_2])
select *
from (
    select name, cast([version] as varchar(30)) as value, concat('v_',[server],'_',instance) as title from YourTable 
    union all
    select name, [user] as value, concat('u_',[server],'_',instance) as title from YourTable
) q
pivot (max(value) FOR title IN (
    [v_x_1],[u_x_1],[v_x_2],[u_x_2],[v_y_1],[u_y_1],[v_y_2],[u_y_2]
  )
) pvt;
```

Comment: very helpful, thank You! For the last hour or so I was trying to make this work for me, but couldn't: [link]https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/